# Shared memory-Dictionary in webservice (asmx)

Tags: c#, web-services, list, backgroundworker

I have a Dictionary of BGworkers(and int) which im using on my asmx webservice.
this list has to be shared accross users which call this web service.

**The list class looks like this:**

```
sealed class ResourcesBG
{
    public static readonly ResourcesBG Instance = new ResourcesBG();
    private ResourcesBG()
    {
        BGWorkersShared =
                new Dictionary<int, BackgroundWorker>();
    }
    public Dictionary<Int32, BackgroundWorker> BGWorkersShared;
```

**tried many ways to achives this goal without any success.**
allso tried :

```
    public static class ResourcesBG
{

    public static volatile Dictionary<Int32, BackgroundWorker> BGWorkersShared =
                new Dictionary<int, BackgroundWorker>();
}
```

the main reason for that is that i could have monitor the amount of thread (bgworkers) in my system and i could abort them whenever i want.
each time i tried diferent method\way, when i start few bgworkers i get list count zero.

**how is it possible to share this list across this webservice?**

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is only for Windows Forms applications, not ASMX web services. Also, ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I defenitly agree, but this is not a new develop,Im working on a old asmx webservice that allready working for few years.

Comment: You still can't use BackgroundWorker in an Asmx

Comment: is it recommendation or fact ? (because its working fine for me)

Comment: can you help me find a way to share memory in this way? lets say its dictionary <int,string> is it even possible ?

Comment: ASP.NET and Task Parallel extension already provides better way of what you are trying to do, why don't you simply create and perform asynchronous task and let IIS handle thread management?

Comment: the basics of this asmx is to run a process on a server and wait for the exit code. we are working with iis6, can you suggest tools for your recomendation ?